# MongoDB default port change

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, mongodb

I want to change the default port of MongoDB in Ubuntu 12.04 for security purposes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Changing the port number isn't real security. If you want security you need to restrict the source of connections if possible, and use TLS and authentication.

Answer (score 4):

Change the line in /etc/mongod.conf.

`port=21707`
to
`port=9999`

if that's what you prefer. Make sure to change all instances of mongodb to the same port so the cluster can communicate.

Comment: you can also pass it as an argument to the binary in the upstart script as `--port 9999` - exact same effect, but thought I would mention it as an alternative

Comment: True, though the conf file is probably the more logical place to look.